# How can I know where a specific element of my website is at?

Tags: magento-1.8

So I bought a template for Magento store and now there is a menu which I want to edit. Is there a way that I can find out in which file is a code for that menu so I can edit it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the template path hints.
Go to `System->Configuration->Developer`. Select your website from the top left dropdown (it doesn't work with global config) and in the section `Debug` set the fields `Template Path Hints` and `Add Block Names to Hints` to `Yes`. Save, clear the cache and look in the frontend.
You should see a lot of red background texts. Those tell you which template (and which block) renders each section of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Go To:

Select `store/website` from Top Left

> System>Configuration>Developer

Go to:

> Debug > Template Path Hints : Yes